# Endless amounts of one line of code, removed after event, produced after another

Tags: python, pygame, lines, blit

My game shoots a bullet, but the problem is you cannot shoot more bullets than the amount you put in (imageA, imageB, imageC, etc...) So, I'd have to write "blit blah blah imageA" about 30 times for every gun for every player. This is just irritating.

Is there anyway to produce code depending on how many bullets the character has shot, and then to produce a code to blit it?  I could then remove that new code when it goes off the screen.   (I just want to know how to remove, not how to make it do it when it goes off the screen, I know that.)

Comment: It sounds like you're dynamically creating CODE. Is this true? because it shouldn't be.

Comment: What are imageA, imageB ??

Comment: You could store all of the bullets in a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), in which case you only need a single variable for an unlimited number of bullets.

Comment: @Kevin i'm afraid the amount of bullets is limited by the amount of memory :P

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are approaching the problem in the wrong way.
Let's say you have a player, that has a gun. So our player class will partly look like this:

```
class Player
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = [0,0]
        self.bullets = []
```

we will also need a bullet class, that will have a position too.
Now, everytime the player presses spacebar for example, you will add a new bullet to the list.

```
def shoot(self):
    self.bullets += Bullet(self.position)
```

then, in the while loop, where you draw your player, you will also need to do a foreach to also draw the bullets. There is no need to name each bullet, and even have an own picture.